# nginx move default "params" files in a subfolder

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx on Debian 10 but installed it from the official nginx repository, not the Debian repository.

In the folder `/etc/nginx/` I have the following files:

`fastcgi_params`, `scgi_params` and `uwsgi_params`

I wanted to move these files in a subfolder: `/etc/nginx/snippets/`. Simply because I have all my "partial" files in that subfolder.

I know that I have to change the path to the files in my vhost configuration, if I want to use them.

**Is this a bad idea?**

Will these files maybe get overwritten by an update?

Does nginx itself need these files at the default location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**nginx** only looks for the main configuration file (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` on Debian) in a fixed location, unless you provide a new location as a command line option (`-c`). All the other files are included from `nginx.conf`.

The files you want to move are marked as [conffiles](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#conffiles), so if you modify them the upgrade scripts will ask you what to do with them.